# Subclass UIButton to show visual feedback when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to implement a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019813/how-to-make-ios-button-give-visual-feedback-when-pressed) I found in another thread but I fail. In interface builder I used the custom class ZFRippleButton for the UIButton class and I changed the type to Custom and State Config to Highlighted. This is the code I used:

```
@interface ZFRippleButton : UIButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;

@end

@implementation ZFRippleButton

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self makeBorder];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)makeBorder {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
}

@end
```

My purpose is to get a circle with a custom color when I tap the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted is the solution to the OP’s first question: “Put an outline around a regular iOS button?”

Comment: What kind of circle do you want to add? Just a static circle or ripple effect animation?

Comment: @yusuke024 Just a static circle